# Can you easily and efficiently copy or edit the INSERTED table in a trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers, sql-server-2012

I'm writing a trigger in which I need to check the incoming data and potentially change it.  Then later in the trigger I need to use that new data for further processing.  A highly simplified version looks something like this:

```
        ALTER TRIGGER [db].[trig_update]
           ON  [db].[table]
           AFTER UPDATE
        AS
        BEGIN

            DECLARE @thisprofileID int

            IF (Inserted.profileID IS NULL)

            BEGIN

                SELECT  @thisprofileID=profileID
                FROM    db.otherTable
                WHERE   userid      = @thisuserID;

                UPDATE  db.table
                SET     profileID   = @thisprofileID
                WHERE   userid      = @thisuserID;

                -- XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                -- XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

            END

            IF ({conditional})

            BEGIN
                UPDATE db.thirdTable
                    SET [profileID] = Inserted.profileID
                        ...{20+ other fields}
                    FROM Inserted ...{a few joins}
                    WHERE {various criteria}
            END
        END
```

The problem that we're running into is that the update statement fails because Inserted.profileID is null, and thirdTable.profileID is set to not allow nulls.  table.profileID will never stay null; if it is created as null then this trigger should catch it and set it to a value.  But even though we're updated 'table', Inserted still has the null value.  So far it makes sense to me why this is happening.

I'm unsure how to correct the problem. In the area with commented Xs I tried running an update query against the Inserted table to update profileID, but this resulted in an error because the pseudo-table apparently can't be updated.  Am I incorrect in this presumption?  That would be an easy solution.

The next most logical solution to me would be to INSERT INTO a table variable to make a copy of Inserted and then use that in the rest of the trigger, but that fails because the table variable is not defined.   Defining that table variable would require more fields than I care to count, and will present a major maintenance nightmare any time that we need to make changes to the structure of 'table'.  So assuming this is the best approach, is there an easy way to copy the data **and** structure of Inserted into a table variable without explicitly defining the structure?

I don't think that a temp table (which I could otherwise easily insert into) would be a good solution because my limited understanding is that they are far slower than a table variable that lives only inside the trigger.  I assume that temp table also must be public, and cause problems if our trigger fires twice and both instances need the temp table.

Comment: The problem here is that your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. This line "IF (Inserted.profileID IS NULL)" assumes there will only ever be a single row in inserted. That is a very dangerous assumption since in sql server triggers fire once per operation, not once per row. And temp tables are not inherently slower than a table variable. No idea where that came from but it simply is false. A temp table created in your trigger would only exist until the end of the trigger execution.

Comment: @SeanLange Apologies; I should have mentioned the single-row thing.  We're aware of that and logic exists to insure this portion only runs when a single row is updated.  If a temp table is used, won't it be a public table, which could cause an issue if two instances of this trigger run at the same time?

Comment: NO. Temp tables are NOT visible to anything other than the current scope. Unless you use a global temp table, which I would strongly advise to not do. Concurrency is not a concern with temp tables created inside a trigger as each instance would get their own copy of a temp table. What is not at all clear is why you need a table in the first place.

Comment: Instead of updating the inserted table or a temp table, why not just use the `thisProfileID` variable for the rest of the trigger?

Comment: @SeanLange and TabAllerman The update statement is in a block of code that executes during set-based operations.  I know the existing design is not the most elegant approach, but a complete rewrite will need to wait for another day.  I will try a temp table; thank you for your help.

Comment: @Nicholas, Can't you do that using INSTEAD OF trigger?